# Export functionality not working properly with EAV UI Grid

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes, ui-grid

I have added Export button on UI grid in my custom module. Module is create with EAV structure. But when i try to export in CSV only ID Column's data is export, Other column's data are missing.

I have added code for export button on Grid in listing file.

> ../view/adminhtml/ui_component/demo_templatetext_templatetext_listing.xml

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">demo_templatetext_templatetext_listing.demo_templatetext_templatetext_listing.demo_templatetext_templatetext_columns.ids</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</exportButton>
```

I'm using eav structure for my custom module & csv exported only one column

[image]

Can anybody help me to solved this issue? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried only "<exportButton name="export_button"/>" instead of above code ?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried <exportButtton... But it's not worked for me, So i have added export button using above code. Export functionality is working properly. But in CSV only ID's data are export. Other column's data are missing. Because my module is created using EAV flow.